# Import and apply CSS animation to svelte element

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, svelte, svelte-component

I want to apply a CSS animation to any given input field, depending on which value was typed into it.

My .svelte file looks something like this:

```
<script>
    let letterPlaceHolder = new Array(50)
    
    async function submit() {
        //Make fetch to backend with all input values. 
        //Backend returns list of which letters are valid and invalid.
    }
</script>

{#each Array(50) as input, i}
    <input
        type="text"
        maxlength="1"
        bind:this={letterPlaceHolder[i]}
    />
{/each}

<button id="submit" on:click={submit}>Submit</button>
```

When the submit function is called, I get a return from the backend, telling me which letters are valid and which are invalid. I want to apply a Boop animation to all elements with an invalid letter. See the example of Boop action here: https://svelte.dev/repl/e606c27c864045e5a9700691a7417f99?version=3.48.0

How can I apply a Boop animation to selected input elements, that are triggered by the response of the backed?

I'm guessing that I need to import a svelte component that animates any given DOM element that I feed it, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would personally solve this is by also having an array holding the validity of each field and a flag indicating whether to show this state or not:

```js
let invalid = Array(50).fill(false);
let showInvalid = false;
```

Then in your submit function you fill this array and toggle the flag **and** a timeout that turns this flag off again.

```js
function submit() {
  invalid = resultFromBackend;
  showInvalid = true;
  // show the invalid states for 1 second
  setTimeout(() => showInvalid = false, 1000);
}
```

With these 2 combined you can now add and remove a class on the input field itself:

```html
{#each Array(5) as input, i}
  <input
     type="text"
     maxlength="1"
     bind:value={letterPlaceHolder[i]}
     class:invalid={invalid[i] && showInvalid}
   />
{/each}
```

(I also changed here that you bind the `value` to letterPlaceHolder instead of the entire element, since you do not need the element itself).

The invalid class would then simply add the css animation like usual.

```css
.invalid {
   animation: 1s boop forwards running;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

I ended up using the solution posted by Stephane.
In my quest to figure out how to apply the animation, I found the animate.css library to handle the animation. So I added this to my `Index.html` file.

```
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>
```

In my .svelte file I added this part:

```
var animate = false
var invalid = Array(50).fill(false);
```

When looping over the response from the backend I make something like this:

```
function submit() {
  //Fetching result from backend
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if (response[i] === false) {
      invalid[i] = true;
    }
  }  
animate = true;
setTimeout(() => (animate = false), 1000);
}
```

My svelte element now looks like this

```
{#each Array(50) as input, i}
    <input
        type="text"
        maxlength="1"
        bind:this={letterPlaceHolder[i]}
        class:animate__animated={animate && invalid[i]}
        class:animate__headShake={animate && invalid[i]}
    />
{/each}
```